# EF Core 3.1.4 Navigation property returning null in One-To-One relationship

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having a problem where a navigation property is always returning null in a One-to-One relationship in EF Core 3.1.4.

My models are structured like so:

```
    public class UserCredential
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
        public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }   
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }

        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserProfile
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }

        public Guid UserCredentialId { get; set; }
        public UserCredential UserCredential { get; set; }
    }
```

Based off what I understand, that should have been enough for EF Core to infer the One-To-One relationship. But it didnt work so I defined the relationshup in my dbContext like so:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<UserProfile>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(up => up.UserCredential)
                    .WithOne(uc => uc.UserProfile)
                    .HasForeignKey<UserProfile>( up => up.UserCredentialId);
            });
        }
```

I checked the db and there is a foreign key from UserProfile -> UserCredentials defined in the table. Likewise both tables have Id as a primary key.

If I post data to a "addUser" endpoint it will be added correctly in the db.

```
{
    "username": "test3",
    "password": "password123",
    "UserProfile":{
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    }
}
```

[Db Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K51Ds.png)

However "UserProfile" in my model is always null.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>   IronCarp.Identity.Models.UserCredential.UserProfile.get returned null.

I'm using a repository to interact with the db and the method that is returning my data/model seems simple enough.

```
        private async Task<UserCredential> GetUserCredentials(string username)
        {
            return await context.UserCredentials.Where(u => u.Username == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated, I am not sure what I am missing, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to include navigation property in linkq, try something like this:

```
private async Task<UserCredential> GetUserCredentials(string username)
        {
            return await context.UserCredentials.Include(x => x.UserProfile).Where(u => u.Username == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Yep that worked! thank you! Is that the pattern I should employ if I need to return related data then? I was under the impression that ef core would infer the relationship and return it automatically.

Comment: I would prefer you to read below article for understanding eagerly loading.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: I did but since I have low rep it doesn’t display it until my rep goes up.

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was happening intermittently in my integration tests.

It turned out because I was mistakenly registering the EF Core DbContext as `Transient` and not `Scoped`:

```
Services.AddDbContext<SubscriptionsContext>(
            options => options.UseNpgsql(appConfig.DatabaseConnectionString,
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure(3)), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Should be:

```
Services.AddDbContext<SubscriptionsContext>(
            options => options.UseNpgsql(appConfig.DatabaseConnectionString,
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure(3)), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

If you look at the default parameter on the `AddDbContext()` extension method, it's always `Scoped`:

[image]